# work with htaccess without change url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dl.php?id=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

it works perfect. I just have one problem, I insert my site urls and images like these

```
<img src="img/image.gif">
<a href="do.php">
```

its short url not full like

```
<a href="mysite.com/img/image.gif">
```

so when now I open `127.0.0.1/dl.php/1/` I can get

```
$_GET['id']
```

But my links and images want to open from

```
http://127.0.0.1/dl.php/img/h.png
```

but it must be

```
http://127.0.0.1/img/h.png
```

can anyone help me  with this? I can't change all urls in my site and make them full url. I have like 50 page and I want this htaccess just for `dl.php` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants to do this because you're using relative paths in your `src`.

Simply prepend a `/` to your paths, and it will go to the root of your site (ie. relative to the domain), rather than relative from the current folder (of course, not a real folder, but according to the URL your browser doesn't know any better).

```
<img src="/img/image.gif">
<a href="/do.php">
```

Sorry to say but you *will* need to change each path. There is one alternative, but you'd still have to change every path unless `dl.php` contains like a header/footer. In this case, you can append a `<base href=".." />` tag to the header, which will force relative paths to be resolved relative to the path you give it.

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
</head>
```

Comment: so there is no way? i must change all urls?

Comment: @masiharastooyi Sorry, was just updating my answer, yes there is :)

Comment: @masiharastooyi Yes, it's a pretty ancient tag.

Comment: thank you but have new problem now :D i see my site now with RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dl.php?id=/$1 [QSA,L] i cant open any other files :-s

Comment: @masiharastooyi Well yes, you're rewriting *everything* to that script. Stick this above the `RewriteRule`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: with this i get server error  RewriteEngine on  
 RewriteRule: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dl.php?id=/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: You put it on a different line, yes?

Comment: line1: RewriteEngine on line2: RewriteRule: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  line3: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dl.php?id=/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: i can use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php anyway

Comment: No remove the `RewriteRule:` bit, line 2 should just be the `RewriteCond ..`